# Google Fusion Tables & Maps - Detect address in region

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

So, I currently have Fusion table setup as a map with regions in KML.  I also have a search by address. I need to be able to put in an address, search, and determine which "region" that point is in.  Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or even an API (that I can't find) where I enter a lat and long and get a result back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a little JavaScript code. First, it sounds like you have the search box working. You'll want to geocode the address that is entered into the address search. You can then use the lat/lon coordinate of the result to perform an intersects query to find all the features in the Fusion Table that fall within a very small radius (for example, 0.0001 meters) of the entered address. Sample code below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false&region=US">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map, layer;
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var tableid = 297050;

      google.load('visualization', '1');

      function initialize() {

        var options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.5,-122.23),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: "'Delivery Zone'",
            from: tableid
          },
          map: map
        });

        window.onkeypress = enterSubmit;
      }

      function enterSubmit() {
        if(event.keyCode==13) {
          geocode();
        }
      }

      function geocode() {
        geocoder.geocode({address: document.getElementById('address').value }, findStore);
      }

      function findStore(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {        
          var coordinate = results[0].geometry.location;

          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            layer: layer,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: coordinate
          });

          var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'Store Name' FROM " + tableid +
              " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS('Delivery Zone', CIRCLE(LATLNG(" +
              coordinate.lat() + "," + coordinate.lng() + "), 0.001))");
          var query = new google.visualization.Query(
              'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);
          query.send(showStoreName);
        }
      }

      function showStoreName(response) {
        if(response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows()) {
          var name = response.getDataTable().getValue(0, 0);
          alert('Store name: ' + name);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <input type="text" value="Palo Alto, CA" id="address">
    <input type="button" onclick="geocode()" value="Go">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:940; height:800"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that you might get 2 results, if the circle intersects 2 polygons, or you might get false positives, since the radius is not 0.

Comment: Ya, I was just looking at this page.  Though I have an imported shape file of districts that I'm trying to trigger

Comment: This was just enough for me to modify it to do my own thing. Thanks much!